# five hours from Monday to Friday

Tags: meaning, commas

a. You are going to work five hours from Monday to Friday.

b. You are going to work five hours, from Monday to Friday.

Do the above sentences mean that you are going to work five hours per day from Monday to Friday or five hours in all?

Does the presence of the comma affect the meaning in any way?

Many thanks.

Comment: the way that you wrote it meant 5 hours in total

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn’t personally use either of those expressions - they’re both a bit ambiguous. Depending on which one you meant, I’d say either:

> I’m going to work five-hour days Monday to Friday

i.e. five hours per day

or

> I’m going to work five hours between Monday and Friday

if I meant 5 hours in total